# Group collection result based on value

Tags: laravel

How can a group a collection based on their values? For example this one:

```
Collection {#250 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "CASSETE_1" => "500"
    "CASSETE_2" => "500"
    "CASSETE_3" => "100"
    "CASSETE_4" => "100"
  ]
}
```

I need to group it and get a result like this:

```
Collection {#250 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        "CASSETE_1 / CASSETE_2" => "500"
        "CASSETE_3 / CASSETE_4" => "100"
      ]
    }
```

Is that possible?

I used `unique()` but the result is :

```
Collection {#251 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "CASSETE_1" => "500"
    "CASSETE_3" => "100"
  ]
}
```

Comment: maybe use groupBy()?

Comment: Tried too but doesnt work because groupBy uses the key, not the value

Comment: Are these collection coming from table?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-maptogroups

Comment: @sumit no. they go through a process, but that is not relevant in this case

Comment: Do you have control over the process that produces the result? is it your code that returns the collection or third party?

Comment: @sam Its my code, but cant be changed. It is in production already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way to do that , you need to make custom function. This is what I did

1 Convert collection to array

2 Flip it

3 Filter by value and join them by /

4 flip it again

```
$arr=array("CASSETE_1" => "500",
    "CASSETE_2" => "500",
    "CASSETE_3" => "100",
    "CASSETE_4" => "100");
$result = array();
foreach (array_flip($arr) as $k=>$v) {
          $result[$k] = implode("/",array_keys(array_filter($arr, function($elem) use($k){
          return $elem == $k;
         })));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_flip($result));
```

output

```
Array
(
    [CASSETE_1/CASSETE_2] => 500
    [CASSETE_3/CASSETE_4] => 100
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below ( convert the collection into Array first ) :

```
$input = [
    "CASSETE_1" => "500",
    "CASSETE_2" => "500",
    "CASSETE_3" => "100",
    "CASSETE_4" => "100",
  ];

$values = array_unique(array_values($input));

 // output results 
$output =[];
foreach ($values as $v) {
    $index = implode(", ", array_keys($input, $v));
     $output[$index] = $v;
}

print_r($output);
```

**The output should be:**

```
Array ( [CASSETE_1, CASSETE_2] => 500, [CASSETE_3, CASSETE_4] => 100 )
```

*You should be able to construct the index string that you want by changing the ',' with the character that you need.*